# If statement isn't behaving as expected in Swift 4

Tags: swift, if-statement

I'm trying to write an if statement that checks if the user has typed anything into the username and password field. If there are any characters in both field, we set:

```
self.loginButton.isEnabled = true
self.loginButton.layer.opacity = 1
```

If it isn't, we set the first one to false and the second one to 0.2.

This is my code:

```
if self.emailTextField.text!.isEmpty || self.passwordTextField.text!.isEmpty
    {
        self.loginButton.isEnabled = false
        self.loginButton.layer.opacity = 0.2
    }
    else if self.emailTextField.text!.isEmpty == false || self.passwordTextField.text!.isEmpty == false
    {
        self.loginButton.isEnabled = true
        self.loginButton.layer.opacity = 1
    }
```

When I run the app, no matter what I put into the text fields, the button will always be inactive and set to 0.2 opacity. How can I fix this?

Comment: Where did you place this code?

Comment: `addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textChanges(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)` can be shortened to `addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanges), for: .editingChanged)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may think that your code is observing the change in textfield's texts, but it isn't

```
// inside viewDidLoad
 emailTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textChanges(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
 passwordTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textChanges(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
```

And get the changes in here

```
@objc func textChanges(_ textField: UITextField) {
  changed()
}  
func changed() { 
    if self.emailTextField.text!.isEmpty || self.passwordTextField.text!.isEmpty
    {
        self.loginButton.isEnabled = false
        self.loginButton.layer.opacity = 0.2
    }
    else  
    {
        self.loginButton.isEnabled = true
        self.loginButton.layer.opacity = 1
    } 
}
```